# Getting a invalid syntax error trying to run my first program

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting a invalid syntax error while trying to run this code in python. I'm following the directions in the book that I'm using but still keeping getting this message. This is my first week learning python and I want to learn from my mistakes as soon as possible.

I already close and reopen python from IDLE and open the file from the interactive shell.

```
if name =='Alice':
    print('Hi, Alice.')
    elif age < 12:
    print('You are not Alice, kiddo.')
    elif age > 2000:
    print("Unlike you, Alice is not an undead, immortal vampire.')
    elif age> 100:
    print('You are not Alice, grannie.')
```

I expect the code to work from the book.

Comment: Did you notice a difference in colour of text for the last `elif` and `print` lines? Also, your indentation is off.

Comment: I fix the quote and indentures and now i'm getting a name error message in the shell.      if name =='Alice':
NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Comment: Got it to finally work. Had to define the name and age.

Answer (score 0):

In line 7, you wrote:

`print("Unlike you, Alice is not an undead, immortal vampire.')`

It should be

`print('Unlike you, Alice is not an undead, immortal vampire.')`
The first quote should be a simple quote, to match the last quote of your print.

Hope it helps !

edit:

Also, you can put an if inside another if, only use elif after your if.
Think of it like logical block:

```py
if name == 'Alice':
   # logical block of name
   if age > 10:
      # logical block of age
   elif age < 10:
      # same logical block of age, different condition
elif name == 'Bob':
   # same logical block of name, different condition
```